# Which components tend to damage first of a power supply for high voltage?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, damage

Which components tend to damage first of a power supply for a voltage spike or surge?

Comment: The ones that were designed-in with the intent that they take the brunt of the spike or surge?

Comment: @jonk Yes it is. No surge protection.

Answer (score 2):

If a power supply (for example, a computer's switchmode supply)
were to take damage from an AC-line event, one would first
look at the fuse (for fire safety there's almost always one inside),
and if there's a MOV (metal oxide varistor), it's wise to replace it
because it is hard to test.   Finally, there are 'fusible resistor'
elements sometimes employed, which have fuse-like failure
modes, but don't catch fire.  Those components are INTENDED to
receive unexpected voltages/currents, and fail gracefully.

That 'graceful failure' is only guaranteed if you can get identical
replacement components, so discard/replacement of the whole supply should
be given consideration.

Sometimes power problems can toggle a motherboard shutdown,
and there may be a reset procedure required in that case.

Further in to the circuitry, there are input rectifiers, then a high voltage filter capacitor, and a high voltage switch transistor.
These ought not to fail, but... surges are unpredictable.

Surges from sources other than the AC input line will require
other inspection and testing, and ultimately... every component
(and there are a lot of 'em) should be suspected.

Answer (score 0):

1)Check if there is any protection circuit. If a fuse is present in the circuit with proper rating , then its unlikely for any component to get damaged.

2)Lets assume we did not have any above mentioned circuit. If the connection is in series , one with the lowest rating is likely to get burned.
Eg: If 3 resistors connected in series and a HIGH supply will damage the resistor with lowest rating , this means our circuit is now open and other components are protected by the cost of this component.

3)If components are connected in parallel , then any component which is rated to operate below the supply voltage we provided will be damaged.